# DataTables PDF export (pdfmake): how to prevent breaking rows in page breaks?

Tags: jquery, pdf, datatables, pdfmake

I am trying to customize the PDF-Export with *DataTables* (which uses *pdfmake*). All my custom styles are working except `dontBreakRows`, it doesn't seem to make any difference, so table rows contents are being splited in page breaks, instead of keeping them together on the next page when they don't fit in the previous, which is what I had expected.

My *pdfmake* version is 0.1.27 (last one, on the date),
*DataTables* 1.10.12,
*Buttons* 1.2.1

This is my code:

```js
(...)
$.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
    'extend': 'pdf',
    'text': 'PDF A4',
    'orientation': 'landscape',
    'pageSize': 'A4',
    'message': 'Date '+todays,
    'customize': function (doc) {
      doc.content.splice(1, 0, {
        margin: \{0, -32, 0, 8\},
        alignment: 'right',
        image: 'data:image/png;base64,(...)'
      });
      //These styles are working:
      doc.defaultStyle.fontSize = 10;
      doc.styles.title.fontSize = 12;
      doc.styles.tableHeader.fontSize = 11;
      doc.styles.tableFooter.fontSize = 11;
      doc.styles.tableHeader.alignment = 'left';
      doc.styles.title.bold = true;
      doc.styles.tableHeader.bold = true;
      doc.styles.tableHeader.color = '#ffffff';
      doc.styles.tableHeader.fillColor = '#666666';
      doc.styles.tableBodyOdd.fillColor = '#ffffff';
      doc.styles.tableBodyEven.fillColor = '#e9e9e9';
      doc.styles.tableHeader.noWrap = true;

      //It doesn't work:
      doc.styles.tableBodyOdd.dontBreakRows = true;
      doc.styles.tableBodyEven.dontBreakRows = true;
      doc.styles.tableBodyOdd.pageBreak = 'before';
      doc.styles.tableBodyEven.pageBreak = 'before';

      //It doesn't work neither:
      doc.defaultStyle = 
        {
          dontBreakRows: true
        }              
    }

}),
(...)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same problem.
The styles are not working.

For me this worked (depending on the table's position in content):

```
doc.content[1].table.dontBreakRows = true;
```

If you figured out a better way, just let me know

Answer (score 0):

You are using `bodyOdd` and `bodyEven`, so you need to use

```js
doc.styles.tableBodyOdd.noWrap = true;
doc.styles.tableBodyEven.noWrap = true;
```